# Insert .tif figures in latex

Tags: pdftex, tiff

How can I insert .tiff figures in a Latex document(PDf latex document).
I have tried everyting I found in web but nothing.

Please

Comment: As detailed in the dupe, you can't use `.tiff` images directly, you'll have to convert to EPS (for `latex`) or PNG (for `pdflatex`).

Comment: @Joseph Wright How can I convert it, autimatically in Latex document. ?

Comment: Sorry, you can't but ImageMagik's `convert` http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php is your friend. (You can do it automatically by external command execution `\immediate\write18{convert fig.tif fig.png}` but that is an overkill.)